# mysql user connection issue through proxysql

Tags: mysql, proxysql

Frequent Access denied coming for database user connecting through proxysql.

Here is my  environment:

Azure ubunti 18.4 instance with three mysql 8.018 version of master slave

```
     xxx.xxx.xxx.73 (mysql slave)
     xxx.xxx.xxx.75 (mysql master )
     xxx.xxx.xxx.79 (mysql slave)
 Proxy sql version is
```

proxysql --version ProxySQL version 2.0.6-73-gc746bf7f, codename Truls
mysql client is  mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL).

**I also change password authentication value in all mysql node config parameter
 to

```
collation-server               = utf8mb4_general_ci
default-authentication-plugin  = mysql_native_password.
```

**
Still I get access issue from proxy sql connecting to DB server node for same user id and 
password sometime it get access to mysql some time it giving access denied.

```
mysql -h 10.5.0.80 -u <mysql_user > -p <password> -P 6033 -e " SELECT @@hostname ; ".
```

this script some time gets connected and sometimes it won't access and getting message access denied

> ERROR 1045 (28000): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'app_user'@'10.5.0.80' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

You can show the password，*mysql_native_password* style like this:   `*BF27B4C7*********7806E870F64F39`

```sql
select host,user,authentication_string from mysql.user;
```

*mysql_native_password* is not working?
Manually modify:

```sql
ALTER USER 'xxxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xxxxx';
```